# How do I set active tabs from an MVC partial view that has a paged list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying unsuccessfully to find how to maintain an active tab after the page gets reloaded.  I have searched all over the place and feel like my knowledge of jquery is at a level where I am not sure what I'm looking for or what to ask.

The following loads 2 partial views:

**Manage.cshtml**

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" id="surveyList">
            <a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab" class="tbs" data-info="survey-list" aria-expanded="True" id="openTab1">Edit/Lock</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="pagedList">
            <a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab" class="tbs" data-info="paged-list" aria-expanded="False" id="openTab2">Search</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1_1"><p>@Html.Action("_PartialViewDisplaySurveys", "Surveys")</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1_2"><p>@Html.Action("_PartialViewPagedSurveyList", "Surveys")</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second partial view is a paged list:

**_PartialViewPagedSurveyList.cshtml**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<SL>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Surveys", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Find by Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<table class="table">
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Surveys", FormMethod.Get))
    {

        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Survey Year", "Manage",
                 new
                 {
                     SortingOrder = ViewBag.YearSortParm,
                     SelectedSurveyYear = ViewBag.SelectedSurveyYear,
                     SelectedName = ViewBag.SelectedName,
                     SelectedStatus = ViewBag.SelectedStatus
                 })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Manage",
                 new
                 {
                     SortingOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm,
                     SelectedSurveyYear = ViewBag.SelectedSurveyYear,
                     SelectedName = ViewBag.SelectedName,
                     SelectedStatus = ViewBag.SelectedStatus
                 })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Locked?", "Manage", new { SortingOrder = ViewBag.LockedSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Open?", "Manage", new { SortingOrder = ViewBag.OpenSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Status", "Manage",
                 new
                 {
                     SortingOrder = ViewBag.StatusSortParm,
                     SelectedSurveyYear = ViewBag.SelectedSurveyYear,
                     SelectedName = ViewBag.SelectedName,
                     SelectedStatus = ViewBag.SelectedStatus
                 })
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @* Filtered List links here*@
            <th>
                @Html.DropDownList("SelectedSurveyYear",
             new SelectList(ViewBag.UniqueYears, "Value", "Text", "ViewBag.SelectedSurveyYear"),
             "All", new { onchange = "form.submit();" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DropDownList("SelectedUtilityName",
             new SelectList(ViewBag.UniqueUtilityNames, "Value", "Text", "ViewBag.SelectedUtilityName"),
             "All", new { onchange = "form.submit();" })
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DropDownList("SelectedStatus",
             new SelectList(ViewBag.UniqueStatuses, "Value", "Text", "ViewBag.SelectedStatus"),
             "All", new { onchange = "form.submit();" })
            </th>
        </tr>
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Survey)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Locked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Open)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Status)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Manage",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

At the bottom of the partial view I have been trying to find the current active tag and if it's active to keep it active.  However, in the below, even though it sets the pagedList element to active, it reverts back to the first tab always after any click of anything because (I know) it gets set in the main view.

```
<script>
    // find active tab
    var id = $('li.active').attr('id');

    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        alert(id);
        $("#tab_1_1").removeClass('tab-pane fade in active').addClass('tab-pane fade');
        $("#surveyList").removeClass('active');
        $("#tab_1_2").removeClass('tab-pane fade').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');
        $("#pagedList").addClass('active');

        var id2 = $('li.active').attr('id');
        alert(id2);
    });

    @* if ($('li .active'.attr('id')) == 'pagedList')
    {
        // if this is the currently active tab, then execute the below
        $("#tab_1_1").removeClass('tab-pane fade in active').addClass('tab-pane fade');
        $("#surveyList").removeClass('active');
        $("#tab_1_2").removeClass('tab-pane fade').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');
        $("#pagedList").addClass('active');   

    } *@
</script>
```

I have tried all kinds of things, like passing a variable back to the view which keeps what the tab clicked on value is ... to trying to load the view dynamically only when the tab is clicked.  Those both had their own problems and so I thought that I would just focus on trying to do it in JQuery.

Comment: Please see [this](http://chadhaney.me/blog/bootstrap-active-menu). You need to create an `HTML helper` to handle it.